# Get the duration of audio blob stored in azure container using C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

Problem Statement:

**I am reaching out to people in community after searching a lot on how to get the duration of audio blob stored in Azure container using C# program.**

Research Work:

I have seen a lot many libraries in C# (eg. NAudio, MediaInfo, WindowsAPICodePack-Shell etc. ) which help in getting the duration of media file , but that only support the media files stored in the local system path and not the audios placed in cloud.

Talking from blob perspective, it does give length property of blob which returns the size in bytes , which does not suffice my requirement.

Please suggest if there is any way to get the duration of audio blob. 
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You need to know which format the audio file is in. Depending on that and possibly other properties, you can calculate the length from the size. From the size alone you cannot tell how long it would play.

Comment: By other properties , you mean sample rate , sample size etc. 
Also I would like to know isn't there any method provided by ms-azure cloud storage out of the box for the same?

Answer (score 0):

The tool [ffprobe](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html) (from the FFmpeg family) would do the trick. This tool is designed to inspect a media file and return all of the information you require from it.

It can take input as a URL so you can feed it your blob file (assuming the URL is open and doesn't require authentication).

This website (https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips) has some great tips on how to use ffprobe.

From C#, you can simply invoke the .exe using `Process.Start([pathToFFProbe], [Arguments])`. If you're on a Mac, use Homebrew `brew install FFmpeg` to get the tools. Should be just as easy on other platforms.

Arguments such as `-o JSON` will output the data in a JSON format that you can parse in your own application to perform any further calculations.

Comment: Thank you for the information James. Let me try it out .